# Ubuntu Server 18.04 LVM shrinks on reboot

Tags: server, partitioning, vmware, lvm

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 server on a thin provisioned VMWare virtual machine and after running the updates and rebooting the 50G disk now shows as being 3.9G and is 78% used. I can resize the LVM but I would like to know what is going on! Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug in Ubuntu / VMWare causing the thin provisioned disk to shrink the LVM to the used size?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include the output of `lsblk`? My guess is that you set up LVM for the whole group, but only defined a 3.9G volume...

Comment: I've resized the lvm to the full size not so not sure it will help. I selected use entire disk and set up LVM and didn't change any options during the Ubuntu installation. If you think it's worth while in happy to re-create the issue and post a lsblk if you think it's worthwhile?

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and post the output of `lsblk` cc @vidarlo